# Changing the style of each feature in a Leaflet GeoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have been studying the [Leaflet Chloropleth example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html).

In my Leaflet application, I have a jQuery dropdown that, when selected, fires a function that takes the name of a state as an argument. I want to use that state name to update the Chloropleth map.

What is the pattern for changing the style of a Leaflet GeoJSON layer? Should I recreate the layer I created with `L.geoJson()` a second time? It seems as though the layers are drawing on top of each other with that approach.

I can provide a Fiddle if needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's [an example of changing a choropleth to classify on different properties](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth-joined-data-multiple-variables/) - the trick is to call `setStyle` again with different values.

Comment: This seems horribly complex on Leaflet's part. But thank you!

Answer (score 18):

To expand on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25773947/1497596) by **@tmcw**, the strategy is to pass a function to `geojsonLayer.eachLayer()` that changes the style for each feature instance within `geojsonLayer`.

Here is some code that demonstrates this strategy that I lifted and simplified from the code posted on the [Mapbox example page](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth-joined-data-multiple-variables/) referenced by **@tmcw**. My code example changes the style of each of the feature instances within `geojsonLayer` based on the value of a **specified property** on each feature instance.

```js
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(...); // a GeoJSON layer declared in the outer scope

function restyleLayer(propertyName) {

    geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function(featureInstanceLayer) {
        propertyValue = featureInstanceLayer.feature.properties[propertyName];

        // Your function that determines a fill color for a particular
        // property name and value.
        var myFillColor = getColor(propertyName, propertyValue);

        featureInstanceLayer.setStyle({
            fillColor: myFillColor,
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            weight: 0.5
        });
    });
}

restyleLayer('myProperty');
```

Comment: It's bad style to have the gejsonLayer as 'global' variable. Just pass it as parameter to the function and it would be reusable. Otherwise you could just delete the function and everthing would work the same way.

Answer (score 7):

The official documentation of Leaflet explains that:

https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

> The style option can be used to style features two different ways. First, we can pass a
> simple object that styles all paths (polylines and polygons) the same way
> ...

> Alternatively, we can pass a function that styles individual features based on their
> properties. In the example below we check the "party" property and style our polygons
> accordingly ...

```
L.geoJSON(states, {
    style: function(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.party) {
            case 'Republican': return {color: "#ff0000"};
            case 'Democrat':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Unfortunately, the names of the styles are not equal to css style names.
For example, instead of 'stroke' use 'color' and instead of 'stroke-width' use 'weight':

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path-option

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for exactly that :)